# Single update statement to update multiple rows mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I was working on generating customized report for an Online College Mgmt Systm and stuck here badly,

I have a master table named say `report` which has 10 rows i,e students with roll no 1 to 10. The attributes are `roll`, `name` and `cs101` [this is the subject code and created with default value 0].

i have another table say `each_subject_cs101` with fields `roll`, `name` and `marks`. But it may not have all the 10 students registered here, say 8 students are there (with roll 1 to 8..to make it simpler).

Now what i want is to update `report` set `cs101` = `marks` from `each_subject_cs101` of those students who are present in `each_subject_cs101`.
THIS WHOLE THING IN A SINGLE UPDATE STATEMENT.

NOTE: The roll no field is a primary key both the tables

What will be the query in MySQL ??

[P.S: Actually all the above mentioned structures are more complex and created dynamically. I used aliases here to make it simpler]

Comment: Any reason you want THIS WHOLE THING IN A SINGLE UPDATE STATEMENT?

Comment: Yes because, the whole logic will have at least five such subject codes and more than 60 students registered in the db, so running a loop for (60X5) times fetching each roll no at a time n updating will increase the complexity time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE report r, each_subject_cs101 escs 
SET r.cs101 = escs.marks
WHERE r.roll = escs.roll
```

---

```
UPDATE report r
JOIN each_subject_cs101 escs
    ON escs.roll = r.roll
    SET r.cs101 = escs.marks;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you establish some kind of joining condition? (I ask because I have never seen this syntax before)

Comment: @asermax it's an old syntax of join. the join condition is on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @asermax It'd depend on how many fields with same `roll` exist in both tables. If they both have `roll` as UNIQUE, it wouldn't be necessary

Comment: @asermax Updated reply with JOIN clause.